Laravel 10 & PHP 8.1 - Cannot npm run dev
Getting this issue when I tried running the command npm run dev.
    error when starting dev server:
Error: Unable to find the configuration file [C:\Users\LP-266\.config\herd\config\valet\config.json].
    at resolveDevelopmentEnvironmentTld (file:///C:/laragon/www/tenant-portal/node_modules/laravel-vite-plugin/dist/index.js:358:11)
    at resolveDevelopmentEnvironmentServerConfig (file:///C:/laragon/www/tenant-portal/node_modules/laravel-vite-plugin/dist/index.js:320:94)
    at config (file:///C:/laragon/www/tenant-portal/node_modules/laravel-vite-plugin/dist/index.js:39:50)
    at runConfigHook (file:///C:/laragon/www/tenant-portal/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CzJTQ5q7.js:67013:25)
    at async resolveConfig (file:///C:/laragon/www/tenant-portal/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CzJTQ5q7.js:66464:12)
    at async _createServer (file:///C:/laragon/www/tenant-portal/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CzJTQ5q7.js:63048:18)
    at async CAC.<anonymous> (file:///C:/laragon/www/tenant-portal/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:735:20)

I have no clue what to do

did you run valet install also make you run npm install before starting the development server?

Try creating new file:
C:\Users\LP-266\.config\herd\config\valet\config.json
that contains only curly braces:
{}

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I think this is a bug. Had the same issue. I had installed and removed Herd for testing purposes. Just to check it out. After that npm run dev crashed. I had neither Herd nor Valet installed. The solution was to remove the Herd directory C:\Users\LP-266.config\herd\ (i my case another user of course)
